# How can I update a web page remotely? Using a web service or email, no direct server access

Tags: html

How can I update a web page remotely? Is there a web service or can I do it via email, I have no direct access to the server.

We simply need to add an alert facility in an emergency. For example simple text message across the top of the home page saying "We are shut today due to bad weather".

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't already got something set up to do this, then there probably isn't any way to do it without access to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell that I catch what you mean, but I will answer in general manner

1- **if you are building the whole site from scratch:** You can create your site by any CMS like [dotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) or [joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) which will allow you to login and edit what you want

2- **if you are building just this page from scratch :** You can build your page with online-editing in mind, in this case I recommend to build two pages one for for viewing content and the other for online-editing you can use any HTML-Editor control like [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)

3- **if you are dealing with already built page :** it will be easier to build administration page which you can upload the new version of the content page to it, and the administration page take care of replacing the content page

hope this can help you, if not, please feel free to clear your needs so we can help more

Answer (score 0):

Contact the host server company you have your DNS/Host service/name resolution with and ask them to redirect the DNS calls to another server of your choice with the notice you wish to have people see when they try to access your page.

Answer (score 0):

On a general basis, yes it's possible, that's what most blog engines and CMS are for. It's also fairly easy to develop an ad-hoc program if all you need is to be able to put an offline page.
If what you mean however is you need to do today witout any access to the server, contacting the person hosting your site or your DNS are indeed your best chances.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting someone to put a [twitter](http://twitter.com/) widget on the page, then you can sms/email or use a web browser to send your updates and they will automatically appear on the site.

Is it at all possible for you get someone to do that for you? [Twittercard](http://twittercard.com/) can be used to generate the code to drop in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this thread is a bit dated, but for anyone still looking for a way to [update your site using email](https://www.sitemailcms.com/), you might want to check out https://www.sitemailcms.com/.  It's a service I've developed to do just that.

Comment: FYI, this looks like you are promoting a product, which will get this answer flagged as spam. If you are promoting a product with which you have any affiliation, [you must identify your relationship to it in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).